# How to run an ansible playbook as a cron job?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm a new ansible user. I want to use ansible playbook as a cron job i.e. run `ansible-playbook site.yml` command on a specific day/date. I set up the command using crontab -e which seems to be working fine.

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```sh
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
  "ansible_facts": {}, 
  "changed": false, 
  "failed_modules": {
    "ansible.legacy.setup": {
      "cmd": "sysctl hw.model", 
      "failed": true, 
      "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
          "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", 
          "filter": "*", 
          "gather_subset": ["all"], 
          "gather_timeout": 10}}, 
          "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sysctl'", "rc": 2
        }
      }, 
      "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup"
    }
```

The extended error stack:

```sh
PLAY [First Playbook] ansible.cfg inventory site.yml TASK [Gathering Facts] fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"cmd": "sysctl hw.model", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", "filter": "*", "gather_subset": ["all"], "gather_timeout": 10}}, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sysctl'", "rc": 2}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup
"}  
localhost : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

site.yaml file content:

```yaml
- name: First Playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "1 2"
```

Inventory file content:

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

ansible.cfg file content:

```yaml
[defaults]
inventory=inventory
```

I am using macOS. I installed ansible using brew (not pip), and I'm targeting localhost.

If my understanding of the error message is correct, ansible is looking for fact.d in the default
location /etc/ansible/facts.d. I tried creating ansible.cfg in the project directory, but
I am not sure if the fact file also needs to be created and/or specified.

Comment: Isn't this failing when run manually as well? Your fact gathering is trying to run sysctl. Did you define localhost explicitly in your inventory? If yes how does this definition looks like? And please show the playbook and add the context of the error (i.e. task title).

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator,  thanks for your help here.

- No, it's not failing when I run manually.
  
- I believe I have localhost defined correctly in inventory file. I edited the question to add content of inventory file.
  
- The added playbook content in the question too.
  
- I added the entire error message. I hope it explains the required context.

Comment: What do you aim to do with this playbook? If nothing is related to the facts of the host, you can simply fix it using [`gather_facts: no`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#disabling-facts)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for your help. `gather_facts: no` works fine, but I need facts for the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `$PATH` is not updated with the path of `sysctl` when running from cron.

Either specify full path of `sysctl` binary when invoke it or pass the `$PATH` variable before the crontab invokation.

Comment: Hi Telinov, thanks for your help here. Could you please tell me how I can specify full path of sysctl binary? When I run `which sysctl`, I got `/usr/sbin/sysctl`. Does it need to be specified as command line argument?

Comment: Which user is running the cron task ?

Comment: The logged in user i.e. self (not root)

Comment: I could be wrong, but based on the error, I believe ansible is not able to find fact_path. /etc/ansible/facts.d doesn't exist on my machine.

Comment: @qwert-poiuy: you are effectively wrong. The local custom facts directory is totally optionnal and is not generating any error. The problem is that ansible cannot find the `systctl` binary when running its `setup` module.

Comment: @qwert-poiuy 3 things to try: 1) run the cron as root 2) use privilege escalation in your playbook 3) modify `PATH` with and `environment` stanza on your play

Comment: @Zeitounator, thanks for patiently helping me on this issue. I appreciate your advice. Unfortunately, none of them worked for me. Just curious, if this issue is related to systctl (which I still don't understand well), then why does the cronjob works if I add `gather_facts: no` in the playbook? Are they related?

Comment: This disables automatic facts gathering, i.e. running the setup module which is trying to run sysctl as part of information gathering.